# KLatexFormula fails to show any formula

Tags: 14.04, ghostscript

I have freshly installed KLatexFormula under a 14.04 LTS ubuntu. It starts fine, but it does not convert any formula I type. instead it opens an error window with the following text:

```
gs reported an error (exit status 1). Here is full stderr output:
GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
And here is full stdout output:
Error: /undefined in 1,000000
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval-- --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1916   1   3   %oparray_pop   1915   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1899   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push       --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
--dict:1174/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
Current file position is 42356
```

Is there any way to fix this or any ideas why this fails?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I didn't found any solution on google.
So, I switch to EqualX -> http://equalx.sourceforge.net/index.html

Its a good alternative...
Cheers,